# Why is UnderscoreJS throwing this error?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

Just playing with Backbone and Underscore, I ran across this error:

```
 
  ReferenceError: can't find variable: search_label
```

Here's the whole code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Router Example</title>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                
   </head>
   <body>
   <script type="text/template" id="search_template">
     <label><%= search_label  %></label>
     <input type="text" id="search_input" />
     <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
   </script> 
   <div id="search_container"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
          this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
           var variables = {search_label: "My Search"};

           var my_template = _.template($('#search_template').html(), variables);

           this.$el.html(my_template);
        }
       });

       var search_view = new SearchView({el: $('#search_container')});
    </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Why is it complaining about the ***search_label*** and how can it be resolved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`_.template()`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) method has a breaking change in recent versions (`1.7.0` onward),

Now the second argument of `_.template` is a settings object, not the data for template. It returns a template function that accepts the data and returns the actual HTML.

So you should do

```
 var my_template = _.template($('#search_template').html());
 var html = my_template(variables);
```

Comment: Thanks.....that simple knowledge fixed the issue.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD by the way have `template: _.template($('#search_template').html())` in view definition and do `this.$el.html(this.template(variables));` inside render... Somewhat more readable and consistent imo...

Comment: Okay.....will keep that in mind